# How can I get array like this?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in variable and I want to put some elements between elements of these array. How can I make these?
Here is var_dump of my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => HOME
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /site/home
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Contact
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /site/contact
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => Contact2
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /site/contact
                )

        )

)
```

Here is a php:

```
$itemsStatic =  [

        ['label' => 'HOME', 'url' => ['/site/home']],
        ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
        ['label' => 'Contact2', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],

    ];
```

Then I would like to put some elements between Contact and Contact2 and I call a function that must return elements:

```
$itemsStatic =  [

        ['label' => 'HOME', 'url' => ['/site/home']],
        ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
        getElements(),
        ['label' => 'Contact2', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],

    ];
```

Here is a function:

```
function getElements()
{

    $ret = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i<2; $i++){
        array_push( $ret, ['label' => 'HOME'.$i, 'url' => ['/site/home']]);
    }

    return $ret;



}
```

I getting these array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => HOME
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /site/home
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Contact
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /site/contact
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => HOME0
                    [url] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /site/home
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [label] => HOME1
                    [url] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /site/home
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => Contact2
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /site/contact
                )

        )

)
```

But I need to get array like these:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => HOME
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /site/home
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Contact
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /site/contact
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => HOME0
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /site/home
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [label] => HOME1
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /site/home
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [label] => Contact2
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /site/contact
                )

        )

)
```

Highly important for me to call a function like I describe above. 
Can anybody help me with these?

Comment: That is not really possible. By putting `getElements(),` in there you are adding the complete return value of that function as one _single_ array element in that position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_splice`](https://www.php.net/array_splice) to insert data into array at certain position:

```
array_splice($itemsStatic, 2, 0, getElements());
```